# Integer overflow in C++ even when using `unsigned long`

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use C++ to calculate a number for me, but I got a wrong answer. I think it might to do with the data type?

I tried to convert all numbers to unsigned long before multiplying, but the result is the same.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
    unsigned int width = 8864;
    unsigned int height = 5288;
    unsigned int NImg = 50;
    unsigned long TotalBytes;

    TotalBytes = (width * height * NImg + 2 ) * 2;

    cout<<TotalBytes<<endl;

    }
```

TotalBytes should be calculated as 4687283204, but the c++ code gives me 392315908.

Thank you very much

Comment: Apparently, `unsigned long` is 32-bit on your platform. Try `unsigned long long`, it should be able to fit your results.

Comment: Can also use the fixed-width types from `cstdint` to be explicit about it.

Comment: When working with C++ and running into "issues" like this it makes a whole lot of sense to mention which OS and compiler you are using. Since different implementations have different max sizes for different types. The only thing mentioned in the standard is often the minimum size that should fit in a given type.

Comment: An `unsigned long` is not guaranteed by the C++ standard to support a value greater than `4294967295` which is less than the value you are trying to calculate.   If you want a larger value, use `unsigned long long`.   Bear in mind that `unsigned long long` is not unlimited either - the maximum representable value is larger than that represented by an `unsigned long`, but is still finite.

Comment: you could multiply them step by step. the intermediate multiplications overflow because of automatic type casting of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your platform `unsigned long` is also 32 bits, just like `unsigned int`. That's not big enough to store the result of the calculation. You'll have to use `unsigned long long`, or if you'd prefer, you could use `uint64_t`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint64_t width = 8864;
    uint64_t height = 5288;
    uint64_t NImg = 50;
    uint64_t TotalBytes;

    TotalBytes = (width * height * NImg + 2 ) * 2;

    cout<<TotalBytes<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning `uint64_t`. These type aliases should be used if a certain bit width is required.

Comment: It really should be `uint_least64_t` (or, perhaps, `uint_fast64_t`), which will always be large enough to hold the result. After all, the goal here is **not** to have a specific size, but to have a size that's **large enough**. Further, `uint_least64_t` is required to exist on all conforming platforms, but `uint64_t` is not. Granted, situations where `uint64_t` doesn't exist would be quite rare, but there's no harm here in avoiding that (rare) problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Big Integer. You can create a class or use someone's library to implement it. For example, http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/108176/

Comment: Overkill. 64-bit int is sufficient.